# Optimize SQL for two different category - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, union

I have a table that looks like

| UserId | Source | HeartRate | BreathRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | 100 | 67 | 20 |
| uuid | 200 | 67 | 24 |
| uuid | 100 | 67 | 21 |
| uuid | 200 | 67 | 19 |
| uuid | 100 | 69 | 25 |
| uuid | 200 | 69 | 22 |
| uuid | 200 | 69 | 23 |

```
(select
    "UserId",
    "Source",
    avg(case when "HeartRate" > 0 then "HeartRate" end)::int as "HeartRate",
    avg(case when "BreathRate" > 0 then "BreathRate" end)::int as "BreathRate"
    from vitals
    where "UserId"='66fd490f-4d93-47d1-bc65-085f676bdaf2' and "Source"=200
    group by "UserId", "Source" order by "UserId")
    union
(select
    "UserId",
    "Source",
    avg(case when "HeartRate" > 0 then "HeartRate" end)::int as "HeartRate",
    avg(case when "BreathRate" > 0 then "BreathRate" end)::int as "BreathRate"
    from vitals
    where "UserId"='66fd490f-4d93-47d1-bc65-085f676bdaf2' and "Source"=100
    group by "UserId", "Source" order by "UserId")
```

The above query results into 2 results if there are 2 distinct sources. One for `Source=100` and the other for `Source=200`. The number of rows in result should be (provided enough data is available) equal to number of distinct `Source` values.

How can the above query be changed such that it doesn't depend on the union of multiple selects and static values of `Source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the filtering condition:

```
select "UserId", "Source",
       avg(case when "HeartRate" > 0 then "HeartRate" end)::int as "HeartRate",
       avg(case when "BreathRate" > 0 then "BreathRate" end)::int as "BreathRate"
from vitals
where "UserId" = '66fd490f-4d93-47d1-bc65-085f676bdaf2' 
group by "UserId", "Source"
order by "UserId", "Source";
```

If you want particular sources, you can use `and` Source" in (100, 200, . . . )`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this :

```
select
    "UserId",
    "Source",
    avg(case when "HeartRate" > 0 then "HeartRate" end) :: int as "HeartRate",
    avg(case when "BreathRate" > 0 then "BreathRate" end) :: int as "BreathRate"
from vitals
where
    "UserId" = '66fd490f-4d93-47d1-bc65-085f676bdaf2'
    and "Source" IN(100, 200)
group by "UserId","Source"
order by "UserId"
```